# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck in boot process

Tags: boot, 16.04

So the problem started when my steam client was updating, then i went to the market and when i came back there was this big screen full of text and it was stuck and i couldnt switch to any other tty, so i shutdown the laptop manually and whenever i boot it first grub comes up then i see a bunch of text starting with [ok] then it stops at

```
[ OK ]  Mounting arbitrary file formats
```

Note that the last line differs each time i boot up. And after this text it transfers to tty1 and there is the ubuntu logo with five dots ( the usual boot process) and it gets stuck here... All the other tty s are blank.

Edit 1: k after many many times of booting i have noticed smthing strange, now i can only switch to tty2 + tty6 and when i double switch it goes back to graphical view. And in tty 2 + 6 it says

> Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctlb -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into default mode. <

Comment: After edit 1, i just lost it and hit every key on the keyboard, now all other ttys are accessible but back in graphical view all the five dots under ubuntu logo are all orange...

Comment: Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, atlast i fixed it, i went into recovery mode and selected root shell, first i ran `e2fsck -p /dev/sda1` which gave an error thqt said I should fsck manually without -p or -a flags and i did. It worked. And everything is fine now, but i rlly dont understand how a steam upd can mess up my filesystem...